Fourier Transform of $f(-ix)$?
I never think on the Fourier transform as defined for real signals valued in the $x$-complex domain and real valued also in the $w$-complex frecuency-domain, but in the real domains.
Given a complex-valued function $f(x)$ defined on the real line, and its Fourier transform $F(f(x), w)$ defined by
$$
F(f(x), w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-iwx} dx,
$$
is it possible to uniquely recover $f(x)$ from the values of the Fourier transform of $f(-ix)$, say $F(f(-ix), w)$ for $w \in \mathbb{R}$?
In other words, if we know the values of $F(f(-ix), w)$ for all $w \in \mathbb{R}$, can we determine $f(x)$ uniquely for (almost) all $x$ real number?
I know the formula for time-domain real dilation and not sure if it extends as is to purely imaginary numbers $t$, as asked in Dilation of Fourier transform.

I don't think it's possible. For example, $\sin(i x) = i sinh(x)$. The FT for these are not similar. Maybe not the best example, because the FT for the latter is not known. But you get the idea.

How about evaluating the inverse Fourier Transform at an imaginary value?
Define
$$g(t)=f(-it)$$
The signal $g(t)$ has a given Fourier (de)composition
$$G(w)= \ F[g(t), w]=F[f(-it), w]$$
and can be synthesized by multiplying each coefficient $G(w)$ by its corresponding harmonic oscillator $e^{iwt}$ and then integrating.
For each $t$ perform the Wick rotation, suggested by @Roland_F, $t\to it$ in the latter
$$e^{iwt} \to \ \ e^{iw(it)} = e^{-wt}$$
and then apply the inverse fourier transform to reconstruct the signal in its imaginary time domain $it$ which is (hoping it converges) then given by
$$
 g(it)=F^{-1}[G(w), it]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(w)e^{iw(it)}dw
    =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(w)e^{-wt}dw.
$$
By its definition, $G(w)=F[f(-it), w]$,
$$g(it)=f(-ix)|_{x=it}=f(-i(it))=f(-i^2t)=f(t)$$
and supposing that the original signal $f$ can be analytically continued, then
$$
\boxed{
f(t) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F[f(-it), w] e^{iw(it)}dw,
}
$$
which seems like evaluating the Fourier transform at an imaginary number if the original signal was $G(w)$, but it actually is evaluating the inverse Fourier transform at imaginary time numbers.
This substitution must build the signal in its imaginary time domain and the procedure can be performed with any other invertible transform.
If we see the transformed signal $G(w)$ as the original function in time-domain, $G(x)$, then this gives meaning to evaluating the Fourier transform at imaginary numbers:
$$F[G(x), iw]=g(-iw),$$
as discussed in How to restore a function from its Fourier transform on the imaginary axis?

We have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ e^{i \ k \  x} f(i \ x) dx \ = \ \int_{-i \ \infty}^{ i\ \infty} \ e^{- \ k \  x} f(x) dx $$
what is the relation between Fourier and inverse Laplace transforms, a so called Wick rotation.
The underlying function spaces on the real line differ by the boundary condition at x=0 for causal time forward solutions of transfer linear transfer equations in time, demanding the poles being located right or left of the imaginary line of integration.
In contrast, the Fourier transform is only one of the many unitary basis tranforms without any implications except for absolute integrability.

Indeed your last formula is an explicit inverse Laplace transform using the so called the Mellin's inverse formula, the Bromwich integral, or the Fourier–Mellin integral. I'll check this Wick rotation. For instance seems to me that I have to see $f(x)$ as the Laplace transform of some other function.

....ok so I studied this Wick rotation thingi and came up with a solution using a transform and its inverse. It is easy: Evaluate the inverse Fourier transform of $F(f(-it),w)$ at an imaginary time value. Surprisingly, this also gives meaning to the evaluation of a Fourier transform at imaginary frequencies.
